# How to remove brown dashed lines in Word whose purpose is to show that something is wrong about the formatting?

Tags: microsoft-word

Please note that I already read all related questions, but my issue is different.

I have in some Word documents brown dashed lines across some paragraphs, which apparently come to notify that something is wrong with the formatting there, because when I change the font size of part of a paragraph I get these lines there. This is happening only to some files. When I convert it to a PDF those lines disappear.

Any idea how to get rid of it?

Here is a screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: The brown lines go away at some point in the document and do not present an issue. They do not go into a PDF (as you said). Red Underlines are spelling errors and do not go away.  I do not think they go into a PDF. Blue underlines are grammatical errors and do not go into a PDF.

Comment: For me appearing in Word is also an issue.

Comment: If what you have is related to formatting, then just correct the formatting. I correct my documents as I go and my documents are much better for doing that.

Comment: John, maybe do you know how to turn that feature off, or maybe do you know the name of these lines, which would help a lot?

Comment: Look in Word, Options, Display, then under Under Always show these formatting marks on the screen,  remove the selection for what you do not want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To disable the detection of formatting inconsistencies :

- Open *File > Options*
- Click Advanced on the left
- In the Editing Options section, uncheck "Keep Track of Formatting"
  (which will also disable "Mark formatting inconsistencies")
- Click OK.

[image]